# code only taking input values then nothing happens

Tags: c, data-structures, quicksort

this quicksort program takes input values  in runtime then nothing happening
neither program terminating nor the output is shown.

i check the algorithm twice but unable to finda ny solutions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void quicksort(int a[25],int beg,int end)
{
 int loc, right, left, temp;

 if(beg<end)
  {
    left=beg;
    loc=beg;
    right=end;

    while(loc<right)
          a[loc]=a[right];
          a[right]=temp;
       }
      {


       while(a[loc]<=a[left]&&loc<end)
          loc++;
       while(a[right]>a[left])
          right--;
       if(loc<right)
       {
          temp=a[loc];
    }

    temp=a[left];
    a[left]=a[right];
    a[right]=temp;
    quicksort(a,beg,right-1);
    quicksort(a,right+1,end);

   }
}

int main()
{
   int i,n, a[25];
   printf("Enter the no of elements:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Enter the array elements:");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
 }
 quicksort(a,0,n-1);

 printf("Elements after sorting is:");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf(" %d",a[i]);


 return 0;
}
```

output is not shown.after providing the inputs,the curser freezes in one place

Comment: The first `while` in `quicksort` looks awfully suspicious.

Comment: can you figureout whats suspeciou?

Answer (score 0):

This loops forever:

```
while(loc<right)
      a[loc]=a[right];
```

You should fix your parentheses placement, maybe add a few here and there.